# How to get the last 30 days results with MySQL with 0 value too?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to get all my result of last 30 days, getting 0 when the *count* is 0.

My query is:

```
SELECT substring(mc.publication_date, 1, 10) AS title, count(mc.id) AS quantity 
FROM mymyv_cards mc 
WHERE mc.publicated = 1 AND STR_TO_DATE(substring(mc.publication_date, 1, 10), "%d-%m-%Y") BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY substring(mc.publication_date, 1, 10)
```

And I get this:

[image]

But I would like the result was like:

06-04-2021 --> 1

07-04-2021 --> 2

08-04-2021 --> 0

09-04-2021 --> 0

10-04-2021 --> 0

............... etc etc

I don't know how to do that, can you help me?

Comment: What version is your MySQL? If it's 8, you can use CTE.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: But consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a list of all the dates.  If you don't have one handy, you can create on using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select curdate() as dte, 1 as lev
      union all
      select dte - interval 1 day, lev + 1
      from dates
      where lev < 30
     )
select *
from dates;
```

Then you incorporate this into your query with a `left join`:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select curdate() as dte, 1 as lev
      union all
      select dte - interval 1 day, lev + 1
      from dates
      where lev < 30
     )
select d.dte, count(mc.id)
from dates d left join
     mymyv_cards mc 
     on mc.publicated = 1 and
        str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') >= d.dte and
        str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') < d.dte + interval 1 day
group by d.dte;
```

Note that a column called `publication_date` should be stored with the value *as a `date`* not as a string.  You should really fix the data model so the data is stored using the correct types.

Also, you might have a numbers table or calendar table lying around in your database.  If so, you can use that instead of the recursive CTE.